# Use the input command in a discord.py script

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a bot that allows someone at the console to (sort of) communicate with people on discord through the bot. However I've come across a problem. The input command doesn't work. I don't really care that it stops the code in its tracks, as I'll be self hosting anyway, and will have to be at the terminal to actually use the bot. The issue I'm having is that the input isn't working. Nothing is displayed in the terminal for the input's message. Here is my code if it helps:

```
enable = True

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    global previousGld
    if previousGld != ctx.guild:
        print(f"{ctx.author}- {ctx.content} \n From- {ctx.guild} \n")
    else:
        print(f"{ctx.author}- {ctx.content} \n")
    if enable == True:
        res = input("Enter response:")
        if res != "n":
            await ctx.send(f"I say: {res}")
            
    previousGld = ctx.guild
```

Comment: Try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58461085/12451222) instead of `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! I used both @Ceres's tip about aioconsole, as well as a try statement to circumvent it. Thanks to everyone who helped out! Here's the fixed code.

```
import discord
import aioconsole

from discord.ext import commands    
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    try:
        if message.author == client.user:
            print(f"\nSent- '{message.content}'\n")
        else:
            print(f"\n\n{message.author}- {message.content}\n")
        res = await aioconsole.ainput('Enter response: ')
        if res == "pass":
            pass
        else:
            await message.channel.send(f"I say: {res}")
    except RuntimeError:
        pass
```

Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score -3):

This is because you don't pass in `ctx` for your `on_message` event. Instead, pass in `message`. Also, as @Ceres pointed out, you should change your input method. Make sure you download `aioconsole` with `pip install aioconsole` in your terminal.

```py
import aioconsole

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global previousGld
    if previousGld != message.guild:
        print(f"{message.author}- {message.content} \n From- {message.guild} \n")
    else:
        print(f"{message.author}- {message.content} \n")
    res = await aioconsole.ainput("Enter response:")
    if res != "n":
        await message.channel.send(f"I say: {res}")
            
    previousGld = message.guild
```

Comment: input is blocking therefore still breaking the command