# Is there a way to send messages from the IDE of python using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, ide, command, python-asyncio

^^

Yes, this question is very, very weird.
I know that IDE is not recommended / prohibited to be used in this way too, but I'm asking because I'm deeply curious :3

Here is my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio
from async_timeout import timeout

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "::", description = "Hey you")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="Hey!"))
    print("Have fun!")

async def salondethe():
    channel = bot.get_channel(123456789101112131)
    await guild.channel.send('test')    

bot.run("token")
```

And I would like to send `salondethe()` in the IDE to send a message in the channel `123456789101112131`
Do you know a way? ^^
Thanks for the curious I am ^^

Comment: You want to start a bot in IDLE, and use IDLE's interactive prompt to issue commands to the bot?

Comment: Just take `input` and send it to the necessary channel. use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454190/python-async-waiting-for-stdin-input-while-doing-other-stuff) for input.

Comment: @user4815162342 exactly

Comment: @Ceres oh thanks! i'll take a look!

Comment: You question and code have nothing to do with IDLE.  You should edit to remove all references to it.  IDLE is a python IDE application that provides a python-specific editor and an integreted gui shell.  IDLE runs user code in a separate process, so most python code, including yours, should run the same as if run directly with the same python.exe from a command line.  (The main exceptions involve user interface io, as discussed in the IDLE doc.)