# Python async input

Tags: python-asyncio

I'm trying to perform some actions during getting input from a user. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58454190/14190526) question but both answers not working for me.

My code:

```
In [1]: import asyncio 
In [2]: import aioconsole
In [3]:
In [3]:
In [3]: async def test(): 
    ...:     await asyncio.sleep(5) 
    ...:     await aioconsole.ainput('Is this your line? ') 
    ...:     await asyncio.sleep(5) 
In [4]: asyncio.run(test())  # sleeping, input, sleeping (synchronously)
```

I'm expecting that input will be accessible during sleeping (or simple counting for example), but it's not happening.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I do wrong?

You used `await`, which (as the name implies) means "wait". If you want things to happen at the same time, you need to tell them to run in the background, e.g. using `asyncio.create_task()` or concurrently, e.g. using `asyncio.gather()`. For example:

```
async def say_hi(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(message)

async def test():
    _, response, _ = await asyncio.gather(
        say_hi("hello"),
        aioconsole.ainput('Is this your line? '),
        say_hi("world"),
    )
    print("response was", response)

asyncio.run(test())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `asyncio` library, user4815162342 provided a great solution. But if you want to use `threading`, you could create a separate thread for handling input like this:

```py
import threading


def write():
    while True:
        input()


def handle():
    #logic or whatever


write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
handle_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle)
write_thread.start()
handle_thread.start()
```